# Find object dimensions in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, collada

Short question. How does one find the dimensions of a mesh in three.js?

I have Collada (.dae) files which I would like to know the size of in units (x,y,z). I have seen comments about using `geometry.computeBoundingBox()`, but I am still not exactly sure how to use it.

Also I am aware of using `scale` but my ultimate goal is to compare objects in the scene with realistic measurements (mm) so it helps to know the exact physical dimensions of an object so that I may change it if necessary.

Appreciate any words of wisdom :^)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using a bounding box sounds like a good idea. You can try something like this

```
    boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(your_object)
    size = boundingBox.getSize() // Returns Vector3
```

Docs:

- Box3: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Box3
- Vector3: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3

Comment update: *Now that I have the object dimensions X,Y,Z, how can I change the value of let's say 'X' and have the object scale to it?*

```
scaleFactor = otherSize.x / mySize.x 
myObject.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
```

Comment: Now that I have the object dimensions X,Y,Z, how can I change the value of let's say 'X' and have the object scale to it?

Comment: `size = boundingBox.getSize()` doesn't appear to be correct, probably outdated use of `getSize()`? See here: https://jsfiddle.net/8L5dczmf/

Comment: I guess its usage was updated. Now a Vector3 needs to be passed into getSize() as an argument. See here for implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/71819811/1757149